# Error in leap year program, test case failure

Tags: java

I'm a beginner in JAVA & I've got this school problem

---

`: Given a year, check if the year is leap year or not. If yes, the output should be “Leap Year”.  Else output should be “Not a Leap Year”.  The input should be a positive four-digit number.  Else,  the output should be “Invalid Year”.`

I can't find the reason for the failed test case described below-

---

Code:

```
if(year>999)
           {
             if(year%4==0)  
                  {
                    if(year%100==0)
                      {
                          if(year%400==0)
                          System.out.print("Leap Year");
                          else
                          System.out.println("Not a Leap Year");
                      }      
                     else
                     System.out.println("Leap Year");
                   } 
                 else
                 System.out.println("Not a Leap Year"); 
            }
            else
            System.out.print("Invalid Year");
```

---

```
12 tests run/11 tests passed     
Error:
Failed tests
Test 1: Check the logic for leap year-1
```

---

For negative input, the output is "Invalid Year" even then the test case fails.

Comment: What do you want it to be? The logic works.

Comment: You are using `System.out.print()` in some places and `System.out.println()` in others.

Comment: based on condition I'd say that `if(year>999)` should be `if(year>999 && year<=9999)`

Comment: @IłyaBursov this was the error. All test cases have been accepted now. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @andrewjames yes, but I altered but that was not the error actually. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error was actually( thanks to @IłyaBursov) :

```
if(year>999) should be if(year>999 && year<=9999)
```

Since input should be a four digit integer.

Comment: Just out of curiosity (or for "bonus points!"): This logic is correct, of course, but why did this fix the (apparently) previously failing "-1" input test case?

Answer (score 1):

change:

`if(year>999)`

to:

```
if(year>999 && year<=9999)
```

Answer (score 1):

You did not check for the year having maximum four digits. Here you go:

```
if ((year > 999) && (year < 10000)) {
    if ((year % 4 == 0) && ((year % 100 > 0) || (year % 400 == 0)))
} else {
    //Invalid year
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Correct program

```
    // Input year is valid four digit year or not
    if (year > 999 && year <= 9999) {
        // Leap year conditions
        if (((year % 4 == 0) && (year % 100 != 0)) || (year % 400 == 0)) {
            System.out.println("Leap Year");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Not a Leap Year");
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("Invalid Year");
    }
```